# ODOO: How to call python function from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, popup, odoo

i have a method that prints a report. That method is not defined inside an Odoo model class, but it is defined inside the website controller. I want to call that method from odoo website, 'My Invoices' section.
The method do something in backend and if it doesn't find some information it raises a Warning error. **I want to show that error in a website pop up, using javascript**.

I found out how to show a simple alert "Hello" in a pop up using the following code:

```
<script>
    function printInvoice(){
        alert("Hello");
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:printInvoice();">
    <t t-esc="invoice.full_name"/>
</a>
```

now i want to call the python method and show the string message it returns inside the alert.
python code:

```
def my_function(self, invoice_report_render):
    try:
       invoice_report_render.get_pdf()

    except Exception, e:
       return e[0]
```

Is there any way to call 'my_function' from javascript above code and put the message in the alert?

Thank you very much

Comment: Javascript can make an HTTP call to your server. Your server can run the function and return a result back to the client, and the javascript can read that result and react appropriately.

Comment: HTTP calls (AJAX) can be made using various libraries, xmlhttprequest, $.get (jquery), or the new Fetch api.

Comment: This question may have been badly worded, but it wasn't a duplicate at all.